# How to make one side of the plane transparent and other side of the plane reflective in Bledner

Tags: reflection

I am trying to create a plane, whose properties are one side of the plane is transparent and the other side of the plane is reflective.

[image: a plane is between the sphere and cube]

in the attached image the plane is transparent but not reflactive.

Answer (score 3):

with this shader setup:

[image]

you will get this:

[image]

either use cycles, or in EEVEE enable Screen space reflections

[image]

and in material use blend/shadow mode alpha hashed

[image]